# inserting data in two database at the same time

Tags: python, django

I have two Models in my application in Django

The Change model is only for storing the change logs made in Model Ip

My models.py

```py
class Change(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='auth.User')
    ip = models.ForeignKey('Ip', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    old_cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    old_status = models.ForeignKey('Status', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    new_cluster = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    new_status =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    change_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Ip(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='auth.User')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, default='')
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('number',)
```

my views.py

```py
def ip_edit(request, id):

    ip_edit = get_object_or_404(Ip, id=id)

    form = EditManagementForm(request.POST, instance=ip_edit)
    change_form = ChangeLogsForm()

    if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():

            ip_edit = form.save(commit=False)
            ip_edit.save()

            change_form = ChangeLogsForm(request.POST)

            if change_form.is_valid():

                ip_change = change_form.save(commit=False)
                ip_change.author = request.user
                ip_change.ip = request.number
            ip_change.save()

        return redirect('/app/management')

else:

    form = EditManagementForm(instance=ip_edit)

args = {
    'form': form,
}


return render(request, 'app/ip_edit.html', args
```

and my forms.py

```py
class EditManagementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ip
        fields = (
            'number',
            'status',
            'cluster',
        )
        widgets = {
            'number': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'ls-form-text'}),
        }

class ChangeLogsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Change
        fields = (
            'ip',
            'old_cluster',
            'old_status',
            'new_cluster',
            'new_status',
        )
```

when I save the ip information editing, no error occurs, but it also does not save the Model Change information

could you help me and let me know if there is any more correct and simple way to store a history of changes in a Model?

Comment: Please can you update your view.py file with correct python indentation blocks

Comment: If you're trying to create some form of audit log (which I think you are) then there are a number of packages availables.  Take a look here: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/

Answer (score 2):

Since your `Change` model has a foreign key relation to `Ip` model and since `ip_change` in your **view.py** presents the instance of `Change` model then you should replace `ip_change.ip = request.number` with `ip_change.ip = ip_edit` because `ip_edit` is the instance of `Ip` model.

Do you want to perform the **save** operation on `Ip` and `Change` models **only when** both forms are valid? If you want that then this code has one really serious problem which people sometimes overlook and that problem is related to **violation of database integrity**. Just try to think about the situation when `form.is_valid()` returns `True` and `change_form.is_valid()` returns `False`. If that happens you will only save the data into `Ip` database table and nothing into `Change` database table because this line `ip_change.save()` will not be reached. If that happens the data integrity will be ruined and I guess you don't want that - you probably want to ensure that both `save`operations either executes or not. You should validate both forms at the same time like `if form.is_valid() and change_form.is_valid()` and put the rest of logic into that block.

P.S.

Since I started to talk about the violation of database integrity you should also have a look at [atomic database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic), it can be useful to know.